# Dataflow: Could not initialize class org.xerial.snappy.Snappy

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My pipeline read data from `GCS` through `Pub\Sub` way, then sink data to redis. It seems work well in `Dataflow` at beginning. However, the following exception found in my pipeline after running two days later.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.xerial.snappy.Snappy
        org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.<init>(SnappyOutputStream.java:97)
        org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.<init>(SnappyOutputStream.java:89)
        org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.<init>(SnappyOutputStream.java:79)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.util.SerializableUtils.serializeToByteArray(SerializableUtils.java:50)
        org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.WindowingStrategyTranslation.toProto(WindowingStrategyTranslation.java:216)
        org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.WindowingStrategyTranslation.toProto(WindowingStrategyTranslation.java:294)
        org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.WindowingStrategyTranslation.toMessageProto(WindowingStrategyTranslation.java:280)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.graph.RegisterNodeFunction.apply(RegisterNodeFunction.java:205)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.graph.RegisterNodeFunction.apply(RegisterNodeFunction.java:97)
        java.util.function.Function.lambda$andThen$1(Function.java:88)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.graph.CreateRegisterFnOperationFunction.apply(CreateRegisterFnOperationFunction.java:207)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.graph.CreateRegisterFnOperationFunction.apply(CreateRegisterFnOperationFunction.java:74)
        java.util.function.Function.lambda$andThen$1(Function.java:88)
        java.util.function.Function.lambda$andThen$1(Function.java:88)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1172)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1000(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:149)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$6.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1028)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is this one issue of Dataflow or my pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per google support, this issue cause by low memory. Several solution could be done as below

> - To reduce your memory requirements in your pipeline.
> - To use a VM with a higher memory allocation.
> - To use Streaming Autoscaling (Not supported in the Apache Beam SDK for Python.) [3]
> - To use Streaming Engine [4]. This allows to move the pipeline execution out of the worker VMs and into the Cloud Dataflow service backend, reducing the consumption of CPU, memory and Persistent Disk storage resources on the worker VMs.

So I add `--maxNumWorkers=15 --autoscalingAlgorithm=THROUGHPUT_BASED` to start dataflow job. It works well now.